# C volatile memory model

Tags: c, multithreading, volatile

Does the `volatile` keyword enforce visibility across threads? For example:

```
volatile int bar;
mutex mut;

void foo()
{
    bar = 4;

    // (*) Possible other thread changes to `bar`. No instructions here,
    // just time that passes.

    lock(&mut);

    // (1) If 'bar' had _not_ been declared 'volatile', would the compiler
    // be allowed to assume 'bar' is '4' here?
    //
    // (2) If 'bar' _is_ declared 'volatile', the compiler is 
    // forced to add the necessary instructions such that changes to
    // 'bar' that may have occurred during (*) are visible here.

    unlock(&mut)
}
```

Not asking about atomicity or ordering (I'm assuming any sane implementation of `lock(mutex)` adds the appropriate memory and compiler fences, where appropriate for the architecture) - simply a question of visibility.

Comment: What do you call "visibility" ? If you mean "that all threads can read or write the variable", the compiler will tell you. If you mean "threads wil see the last value assigned", then the question is indeed about atomicity or ordering. Please clarify.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do mean "threads will see the last value assigned", however, assuming that compiler/memory fences were inserted around `lock`/`unlock`, don't think atomicity or ordering comes into play here.

Comment: If the other thread that changes `bar` runs unsynchronized with the assignment `bar = 4;` in this thread, the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: Sorry but this *is* precisely about atomicity or ordering. Anything can happen between the assignment and the lock, volatile or not. The assignment should probably be inside the crititcal section.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "Anything can happen between the assignment and the lock, volatile or not" - precisely what I'm trying to demonstrate. The assignment *outside* the critical section is meant to demonstrate how there still may be an error if not declared `volatile`

Comment: This site is for asking questions, not for demonstrations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think we are misunderstanding each other. The sample code was specifically structured so we could look at an example of the type of question I'm asking about, and to prevent people commenting about the wrong topic, ex. atomicity and ordering.

Comment: You are wrong. The topic is atomicity and ordering. Visibility is related to scoping, completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, agree to disagree, I guess. The inclusion of the mutex lock should make atomicity and load/store memory ordering irrelevant. Issue is visibility: for example, `bar` can't be stored in register file.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If it helps, put a separate `lock(&mut)`/`unlock(&mut)` call around the assignment, and it's still the same question.

Comment: @user7226419: for the last time, your vocabulary is inappropriate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK, agree to disagree, clearly neither of us thinks we are wrong. Thanks for your time anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't tag `bar` as volatile, the compiler cannot be sure that the value hasn't been modified in the meanwhile since it is a *global* value.

So it has to read it again (mutex functions are called, it could be any function getting access to `bar` and change it), volatile or not.

It would be different for a `local` value, binding, say, on a hardware register that may change independently of the program execution, where the `volatile` keyword would be required.

Comment: "Even if you don't tag bar as volatile, the compiler cannot be sure that the value hasn't been modified in the meanwhile since it is a global value." I don't think this is true? `volatile` came around to service needs of signal handlers (among other things), which would surely operate on global data.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) If 'bar' had *not* been declared 'volatile', would the compiler
>    be allowed to assume 'bar' is '4' here?

The property of `volatile` is really simple to understand: read it from memory location every time without optimising anything in relation that. Whether or not, there are multiple threads, a volatile qualified variable still holds the same property.

Does it mean `volatile` enforces "visibility" across threads?

It may do so as a side effect of its property. But that shouldn't be necessary in a multi-threaded program. Using a proper synchronisation primitive (e.g. a mutex or an atomic variable), a compiler must enforce the visibility or the last stored value in an object across different threads. This is case in both C11 and POSIX threads. A compiler that supports multi-threading programs should be able to generate code correct code that enforces this without requiring `volatile`. So, the answer is no; you don't need `volatile` in multi-threaded programs to enforce changes to objects (variables).

Comment: Sorry, meant to specify C99.

Comment: C99 didn't have threads. So, the standard didn't cover anything related to multi-threaded programs. So we are left with implementation specific behaviour/documentation. The general gist of the answer still holds: if a compiler claims to support multi-threading it shouldn't require `volatile`. I have used (still use) POSIX threads using GCC and `volatile` was never needed.

Comment: The compiler flag `D_REENTRANT` was required for the compiler to understand that it's a multi-threaded program (and enable necessary thread safety etc). But that was a long time ago. It's no longer needed. You can search [comp.programming.threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.programming.threads) for GCC/Pthreads related information.

Comment: C99 may not of had threads as a language construct (I don't think such things should be a part of a language anyways), but many things were multithreaded

Comment: It's times like this where languages get in the way, I find. Perhaps easier to just hand-roll the assembly for supported platforms. At least that takes the guess work out ha!